# SOS how to vertical align text with this specific \newcolumntype?

Tags: tables

I would like to vertical align the text 'Muscular system', which is highlighted in color lavender. I defined a new column type and the correlated questions on this website couldn't help. Thank you in advance!

```
    \documentclass{book}
    \usepackage{dcolumn}
    \usepackage{tabularx} 
    \usepackage{color, colortbl}
    \definecolor{LavenderBlue}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,1}

    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!h]
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
        \centering
         \small
                \begin{tabular}{|P{4cm}|P{7cm}|}
        \hline 
    System & Effects \\
    \hline
        Circulatory system & Pericarditis, heart failure, hypertension \\ \hline
Blood tissue & Anemia \\ \hline
Gastrointestinal system & Nausea, loss of appetite, diarrhoea, stomatitis \\ \hline
Nervous system  & Somnolence, apathy, amnesia \\ \hline
\rowcolor{LavenderBlue}
Muscular system & Cramps, alteration of sensitivity, alteration of neuromuscular excitability \\ \hline
Skeletal system & Changes in bone metabolism, joint inflammation \\ \hline
Integumentary system & Pallor, itching, yellowish colour \\ \hline  
\end{tabular}
\caption{Effects caused by renal dysfunctions on the systems of the human body.}
\label{effectbody}
 \end{table}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: you want to align where? top, bottom, center?

Comment: center, please. But >{\centering\arraybackslash} didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}` by `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}` in your MWE gives you the following result: 
[image]

In general, `p` cells are top aligned, `m` cells are vertically centered and `b` cells align their contents to the bottom of the cell.